# Use opencv C++ on raspberry pi 2

Tags: c++, opencv, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am successfully running opencv python code on raspberry pi 2 (raspbian).
Now I want to try to compile opencv C++ code on raspberry pi 2 by using this command:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test_colour_tracking_1.cpp -otest_colour
```

The C++ coding as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from web cam
    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
         return -1;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        Mat imgOriginal;    
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
             break;
        }
    imshow("image",imgOriginal);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it show error as below.

```
/tmp/ccHcCqSm.o: In function `main':
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::Mat&)'
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text+0x1f0): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
/tmp/ccHcCqSm.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x3c): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccHcCqSm.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
test_colour_tracking_1.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[cv::Mat::release()]+0x58): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I want to ask how to check frame rate per second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test_colour_tracking_1.cpp -o test_colour `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: I will try it later as my rasp pi have problem and i post my question at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/why-act-and-pwr-led-is-on-but-no-booting can u take a look?